# Python scripting: Best method to store and use more complex objects?

Tags: python

Before I move forward with this next step, I'm trying to figure out whether or not it's better to try and capture/code the generation of more complex meshes or to save them in a file bundled with the project.

To keep it from being more opinion based, I'm looking more for "these are the problems you'll find down the road" if, for instance, I try to create an installation package that includes objects a user might need.

For non-Blender projects I normally bundle the binaries in packages and lump them all together. That seems simpler than re-generating more complex meshes, which even a simple pattern can generate a page of code. These would be more or less static objects that may need resizing once imported or appended, but otherwise will only be interested in the whole (and not any of the parts).

Comment: "more complex meshes" - more complex than what? What do you consider to be a complex model? I think the question would benefit from more specific information. What's the actual situation? What are the models? How many are there of them? If you are making an add-on, any files can be packed to the add-on's .zip file and there will not be anything different from installing any other add-on from a .zip file - this is how Blender's add-ons are meant to be made - any files can come with them with the standard installation process.

Comment: Anything more complex than basic building block structures. That answer can vary of course, depending on experience, but for instance I modeled some molding for a door frame by tracing it over a background picture. That's a fairly manual activity which can be capture and scripted. I didn't really find any addons that imported even more complex structures, which is why I'm asking. Maybe that was just to keep a smaller profile; however I haven't taken a look at larger blender projects.

Comment: I do not really understand what exactly you are trying to do or what your goal is to be honest. Are you talking about scripting or using some sort of a library of models in Blender? If scripting, then what exactly are you scripting and how? I assumed an add-on because you mentioned 'installation package', is that a correct assumption? See [Archipack](https://blender-archipack.org/) and [Simple Asset Manager]https://www.blendernation.com/2018/11/19/add-on-simple-asset-manager/ for an add-on examples.

Comment: Being newish to Blender can make it difficult to phrase questions correctly sometimes. What I'm working toward is more than an addon, and will eventually serve as an app built on top of Blender (with a simplified user interface, etc). My past experience is with gui toolkits and using libraries of things imported. However when I look at current Blender addons (such as Archipack), they dynamically generate all meshes (and import nothing, with the exception of some images). I don't understand why that is instead of using a blend file library for some things. Some type of asset manager is correct.